# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/IteratorUtils

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, displaytag

I received this error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/IteratorUtils
```

I have downloaded the newest jar: `commons-collections4-4.0.jar`

And it looks like multiple libs/apps are looking for `commons/collections` (not `commons/collections4`). I am trying to use display tags and get this problem.

Where can I find `commons-collections.jar`?

Answer (score 1):

Commons-collections is an Apache utility - you could try looking at Apache (http://commons.apache.org) or Maven Central (http://search.maven.org).

I must confess I am not familiar with commons-collections4.  However, I would imagine you need to read the JavaDocs and/or release notes to see if any method signatures have changed and upgrade your method calls accordingly.  From your error messages, the package names at the very least are different.

Comment: Thanks, downloaded version 3 instead of 4 and that is working fine. It looks like version 4 has changed name and is different product.